# Android OpenGL ES 2.0 - Texture black

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, opengl-es-2.0, render-to-texture

I am using OpenGL|ES 2.0 to create a simple rectangle. I am not able to get the textures working.My Renderer  & other class files as below.

TextureRenderer.java

```
public class TextureRenderer  implements Renderer {

private final Context context;
private final float[] projectionMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] modelMatrix = new float[16];
private Table table;
private Mallet mallet;
private TextureShaderProgram textureProgram;
private ColorShaderProgram colorProgram;
private int texture;

public TextureRenderer(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}   

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Clear the rendering surface.
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   

    // Draw the table.
    textureProgram.useProgram();
    textureProgram.setUniforms(projectionMatrix, texture);
    table.bindData(textureProgram);
    table.draw();

    // Draw the mallets.
    colorProgram.useProgram();
    colorProgram.setUniforms(projectionMatrix);
    mallet.bindData(colorProgram);
    mallet.draw();

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Set the OpenGL viewport to fill the entire surface.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    table = new Table();
    mallet = new Mallet();
    textureProgram = new TextureShaderProgram(context);
    colorProgram = new ColorShaderProgram(context);
    texture = TextureHelper.loadTexture(context, R.drawable.air_hockey_surface);

    Log.d("TAG",""+texture);

}}
```

Table.java

```
public class Table {

private static final int POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT = 2;
private static final int TEXTURE_COORDINATES_COMPONENT_COUNT = 2;
private static final int STRIDE = (POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT
+ TEXTURE_COORDINATES_COMPONENT_COUNT) * Constants.BYTES_PER_FLOAT;
private final VertexArray vertexArray;

private static final float[] VERTEX_DATA = {
    // Order of coordinates: X, Y, S, T
    // Triangle Fan
    0f, 0f, 0.5f, 0.5f,
    -0.5f, -0.8f, 0f, 0.9f,
    0.5f, -0.8f, 1f, 0.9f,
    0.5f, 0.8f, 1f, 0.1f,
    -0.5f, 0.8f, 0f, 0.1f,
    -0.5f, -0.8f, 0f, 0.9f };

public Table() {
    vertexArray = new VertexArray(VERTEX_DATA);
    }

public void bindData(TextureShaderProgram textureProgram) {
    vertexArray.setVertexAttribPointer(0,
            textureProgram.getPositionAttributeLocation(),
            POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT, STRIDE);
    vertexArray.setVertexAttribPointer(POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT,
            textureProgram.getTextureCoordinatesAttributeLocation(),
            TEXTURE_COORDINATES_COMPONENT_COUNT, STRIDE);
}

public void draw() {
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 6);
    }}
```

Mallet.java

```
public class Mallet {

private static final int POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT = 2;
private static final int COLOR_COMPONENT_COUNT = 3;
private static final int STRIDE =
(POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT + COLOR_COMPONENT_COUNT)
* Constants.BYTES_PER_FLOAT;
private static final float[] VERTEX_DATA = {
// Order of coordinates: X, Y, R, G, B
0f, -0.4f, 0f, 0f, 1f,
0f, 0.4f, 1f, 0f, 0f };
private final VertexArray vertexArray;

public Mallet() {
    vertexArray = new VertexArray(VERTEX_DATA);
}

public void bindData(ColorShaderProgram colorProgram) {
    vertexArray.setVertexAttribPointer(0,
            colorProgram.getPositionAttributeLocation(),
            POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT, STRIDE);
    vertexArray.setVertexAttribPointer(POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT,
            colorProgram.getColorAttributeLocation(),
            COLOR_COMPONENT_COUNT, STRIDE);
}

public void draw() {
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 2);
}}
```

ShaderProgram.java

```
public class ShaderProgram {
// Uniform constants
protected static final String U_MATRIX = "u_Matrix";
protected static final String U_TEXTURE_UNIT = "u_TextureUnit";
// Attribute constants
protected static final String A_POSITION = "a_Position";
protected static final String A_COLOR = "a_Color";
protected static final String A_TEXTURE_COORDINATES = "a_TextureCoordinates";
// Shader program
protected final int program;

protected ShaderProgram(Context context, int vertexShaderResourceId,
        int fragmentShaderResourceId) {
    // Compile the shaders and link the program.
    program = ShaderHelper.buildProgram(TextResourceReader
            .readTextFileFromResource(context, vertexShaderResourceId),
            TextResourceReader.readTextFileFromResource(context,
                    fragmentShaderResourceId));
}

public void useProgram() {
    // Set the current OpenGL shader program to this program.
    glUseProgram(program);
}}
```

ColorShaderProgram.java

```
public class ColorShaderProgram extends ShaderProgram {

// Uniform locations
private final int uMatrixLocation;
// Attribute locations
private final int aPositionLocation;
private final int aColorLocation;

public ColorShaderProgram(Context context) {
    super(context, R.raw.simple_vertex_shader, R.raw.simple_fragment_shader);
    // Retrieve uniform locations for the shader program.
    uMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, U_MATRIX);
    // Retrieve attribute locations for the shader program.
    aPositionLocation = glGetAttribLocation(program, A_POSITION);
    aColorLocation = glGetAttribLocation(program, A_COLOR);
}

public void setUniforms(float[] matrix) {
    // Pass the matrix into the shader program.
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uMatrixLocation, 1, false, matrix, 0);
}

public int getPositionAttributeLocation() {
    return aPositionLocation;
}

public int getColorAttributeLocation() {
    return aColorLocation;
}}
```

TextureShaderProgram.java

```
public class TextureShaderProgram extends ShaderProgram {
// Uniform locations
private final int uMatrixLocation;
private final int uTextureUnitLocation;
// Attribute locations
private final int aPositionLocation;
private final int aTextureCoordinatesLocation;

public TextureShaderProgram(Context context) {
    super(context, R.raw.texture_vertex_shader,
            R.raw.texture_fragment_shader);
    // Retrieve uniform locations for the shader program.
    uMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, U_MATRIX);
    uTextureUnitLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, U_TEXTURE_UNIT);
    // Retrieve attribute locations for the shader program.
    aPositionLocation = glGetAttribLocation(program, A_POSITION);
    aTextureCoordinatesLocation = glGetAttribLocation(program,
            A_TEXTURE_COORDINATES);
}

public void setUniforms(float[] matrix, int textureId) {
    // Pass the matrix into the shader program.
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uMatrixLocation, 1, false, matrix, 0);
    // Set the active texture unit to texture unit 0.
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    // Bind the texture to this unit.
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    // Tell the texture uniform sampler to use this texture in the shader by
    // telling it to read from texture unit 0.
    glUniform1i(uTextureUnitLocation, 0);
}

public int getPositionAttributeLocation() {
    return aPositionLocation;
}

public int getTextureCoordinatesAttributeLocation() {
    return aTextureCoordinatesLocation;
}}
```

TextureHelper.java

```
public class TextureHelper {
private static final String TAG = "TextureHelper";

public static int loadTexture(Context context, int resourceId) {

    final int[] textureObjectIds = new int[1];
    glGenTextures(1, textureObjectIds, 0);
    if (textureObjectIds[0] == 0) {
        if (LoggerConfig.ON) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Could not generate a new OpenGL texture object.");
        }
        return 0;
    }

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            context.getResources(), resourceId, options);
    if (bitmap == null) {
        if (LoggerConfig.ON) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Resource ID " + resourceId
                    + " could not be decoded.");
        }
        glDeleteTextures(1, textureObjectIds, 0);
        return 0;
    }
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureObjectIds[0]);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
            GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    texImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
    bitmap.recycle();

    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); // unbind texture

    return textureObjectIds[0];

}}
```

ShaderHelper.java

```
public class ShaderHelper {
private static final String TAG = "ShaderHelper";

public static int compileVertexShader(String shaderCode) {
    return CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, shaderCode);
}

public static int compileFragmentShader(String shaderCode) {
    return CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, shaderCode);
}

private static int CompileShader(int type, String shaderCode) {

    final int shaderObjectId = glCreateShader(type);

    if (shaderObjectId == 0) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Could not create shader");

        return 0;
    }
    // shader and associate it with shadercode
    glShaderSource(shaderObjectId, shaderCode);
    glCompileShader(shaderObjectId);

    final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];
    glGetShaderiv(shaderObjectId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);
    Log.v(TAG, "Results of compiling source:" + "\n" + shaderCode + "\n:"
            + glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderObjectId));
    if (compileStatus[0] == 0) { // If it failed, delete the shader object.
                                    // glDeleteShader(shaderObjectId);
        Log.w(TAG, "Compilation of shader failed.");
        return 0;
    }

    return shaderObjectId;
}

public static int linkProgram(int vertexShaderId, int fragmentShaderId) {
    final int programObjectId = glCreateProgram();

    if (programObjectId == 0) {
        Log.w(TAG, "couldn't craete prgram");
        return 0;
    }
    glAttachShader(programObjectId, vertexShaderId);
    glAttachShader(programObjectId, fragmentShaderId);

    glLinkProgram(programObjectId);

    final int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
    glGetProgramiv(programObjectId, GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
    Log.v(TAG, "Results of linking program:\n"
            + glGetProgramInfoLog(programObjectId));
    if (linkStatus[0] == 0) { // If it failed, delete the program object.
        glDeleteProgram(programObjectId);
        Log.w(TAG, "Linking of program failed.");
        return 0;
    }

    return programObjectId;
}

public static boolean validateProgram(int programObjectId) {
    glValidateProgram(programObjectId);

    final int[] validateStatus = new int[1];
    glGetProgramiv(programObjectId, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, validateStatus, 0);

    Log.v(TAG, "Results of validating program: " + validateStatus[0]
            + "\nLog:" + glGetProgramInfoLog(programObjectId));
    return validateStatus[0] != 0;

}

public static int buildProgram(String vertexShaderSource,
        String fragmentShaderSource) {
    int program;
    // Compile the shaders.
    int vertexShader = compileVertexShader(vertexShaderSource);
    int fragmentShader = compileFragmentShader(fragmentShaderSource);
    // Link them into a shader program.
    program = linkProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    if (LoggerConfig.ON) {
        validateProgram(program);
    }
    return program;
}}
```

VertexArray.java

```
public class VertexArray {
private final FloatBuffer floatBuffer;

public VertexArray(float[] vertexData) {
    floatBuffer = ByteBuffer
            .allocateDirect(vertexData.length * Constants.BYTES_PER_FLOAT)
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer().put(vertexData);
}

public void setVertexAttribPointer(int dataOffset, int attributeLocation,
        int componentCount, int stride) {
    floatBuffer.position(dataOffset);
    glVertexAttribPointer(attributeLocation, componentCount, GL_FLOAT,
            false, stride, floatBuffer);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(attributeLocation);
    floatBuffer.position(0);
}}
```

I am refering to this two websites [Link1](http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-four-introducing-basic-texturing/) & [Link2](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_3D.html). I just got black screen whenever I run my app. Image is also in power of 2 (512*512) but I am not able to find what is the problem in this code. Please help if anyone knows about it.

Comment: Try adding glBindTexture line every time you draw.

Comment: Try setting the wrap modes at the same point you set the MIN/MAG filters.

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

Comment: If I had a dollar everytime someone asks for OpenGL debugging help without calling glGetError even once...

Comment: You're not using ES 2.0. This looks like ES 1.x all the way.

Comment: @RetoKoradi i have updated code but same problem.